# is it possible for clojure to read and work on classes (.class files) generated by compiler?

Tags: java, clojure

is it possible for read and work on classes (.class files) generated by java code?

e.g.) CalculateSum.java - > CalculateSum.class
-> Clojure takes CalculateSum.class and embed it in its code?

Comment: why embed it rather than use it as an API?

Comment: @Saket You mean use .class files as an api or java code?

Comment: You can just put them in a jar and use

Comment: I mean as an API. Just include it within your classpath (either as a separate Jar, or within your own application libary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure the class file is in your classpath.

Here is some example code.

hello.java:

```
 public class hello {
     public String sayHi() {
         return "hello world";
     }
 }

$ javac hello.java
$ java -cp clojure.jar:./ clojure.main
user=> (import 'hello) ;; Necessary in 1.2.1, but not 1.3.0
user=> (.sayHi (hello.))
"hello world"
```

Comment: I appreciate this concise example. This is the shortest way of doing it. when this gets impractical (as projects grow) use namespaces and leiningen/maven

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt How can we call a jar file made up of .class files of clojure code?

Comment: @bmillare D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (.sayHi (hello.))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: hello (NO_SOURC
E_FILE:1)
user=>

Comment: @vikbehal, You're using windows, so you need to separate items in the classpath with a semicolon. change "java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main" to "java -cp clojure.jar;./ clojure.main"

Comment: @bmillare D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar;./ clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (.sayHi (hello.))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: hello (NO_SOURC
E_FILE:1)

Comment: @vikbehal, did you compile the .java file? with javac hello.java? there should be a hello.class file in your current directory.

Comment: @bmillare yes i have, here is the proof, please check.       Directory of D:\work\test-Clojure

10/07/2011  03:09 PM               653 CalculateSum.class
10/10/2011  10:23 AM               273 hello.class
10/07/2011  05:26 PM               459 Test.class
               3 File(s)          1,385 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  34,791,534,592 bytes free

D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar;./ clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (.sayHi (hello.))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: hello (NO_SOURC
E_FILE:1)

Comment: Since you are using 1.2.1, you need to import hello first (import 'hello). In 1.3.0, you can call (hello.) without importing it.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure was designed to embrace its host platform, the JVM. the clojure compiler produces class files that once created behave just like a class file from any other source; so in effect you are already doing this ;)

If you want to use a java class just put an import statement in your namespace:

```
(ns my.project
  (:import [com.them.library A B C]))
```

then check out

http://clojure.org/java_interop for what to do next

Answer (score 1):

All of Clojure is pure Java and runs on the JVM. It can load and use any valid Java class.

Comment: Clojure has extensive [documentation with examples on Java Interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop).